# What is the best way to share large data in Windows 8 app

Tags: database, windows-phone

I would like to know what is the best way to save a large data in a Windows Phone 8 app that can roam between devices. I know that we have got a Roaming folder but there is only 100kB available space. I would like to save data like customers, their addresses or something like that. Where I can do that and what is the best way for it? Database, Json files? Thanks for any information:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to store data that can **roam between devices**, you should look at creating a web service. Then, every time, read/store data onto the web service by (de)serializing JSON.

However, if you want the data to roam across user's personal devices, say Universal App on PC and phone,

The good news is that if you’re developing a Windows Phone 8.1 app and want to take advantage of app data backup, you don’t have to do much. The first step is simply to understand the options for storing data in the Windows Phone app data model, which is accessible through the `Windows.Storage.ApplicationData` class. Those options are:

**Roaming** This container supports both unstructured data (files) and structured data (settings). Data stored here is eligible for roaming synchronization between the user’s devices (including synchronization between Windows and Windows Phone for universal apps with a shared identity). Roaming data may also be backed up under certain conditions (for example, when the user has disabled roaming) in order to capture the entirety of the app’s state.

In this case, it is better to store user's data as json, if it is simple. If the data is highly complex, its better to use database libs like `SQLite`